# Unable to scroll mobiscroll select scroller in phonegap in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, mobiscroll

I am using `mobiscroll` for selecting values. But the problem i am facing when i scroll down to select other values , it does not scroll down and it bounce back to starting value. I did not get any `error`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it !

The bug was in mobiscroll plugin. I have set rate value "0.00" in option . Some how mobiscroll does not recognised it. So i appended rate and tax name in value and now it is working ok